# Monitoring total robots in system

Tags: factorio

I have automated logistic/construction robot building.  I'm trying to control robot production based on the total number of robots in the system.  Is there any way to monitor the total number of robots as it's displayed in the Roboport status window?

For example, if I want to ensure that I have 100 construction robots and if it falls below that number I'd like to activate my construction otherwise it stays idle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, although only within a given network.

By connecting a Roboport to the circuit network, you can obtain from it the total and available number of both robot types *for that logistic network*.  You can then use this information to cut production of robots (e.g. by deactivating inserters).

If you want, as stated in your example, start production whenever you have less than 100 robots, use the *available* numbers, which count the robots that are currently idle, while the *total* numbers counts all robots in the network, idle or working.

Comment: Makes sense, it never occurred to me to wire up a Roboport for some reason :/

Comment: @SteveH. There are so many items in the game that allow circuit network connectivity that it's normal to miss some, even if they're obvious. Just a few days ago I discovered requesters can set their requests via logistics, and it *blew my mind*.

Comment: You could use the circuit network and combinators to add together the value signals from multiple robot networks to get your total bot amount.

Comment: @Fambida yes, but you need to be *very* careful, because if you join two networks together you will be adding two times the same amount of robots.

Answer (score -2):

I have made a simple design that inserts robots until the logistics count reaches 1000, try this blueprint and adjust your decider accordingly:

`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`